PBI/SSAS - discover_object_memory_usage help needed
I was trying to see what's using a big chunk of our memory when we are refreshing PBI semantic models. Stumbled upon $System.discover_object_memory_usage, tried it in DAX Studio and gave me an error. Apparently, I do not have administrator rights. My question is, where do I need to set this up?
Is it in PBI service workspace access settings? (We can add users in there and select corresponding roles: Admin, Contributor, Viewer
Or in the actual corresponding instance of Analysis Service of the workspace? Also, if this is the case, who is the default Admin of AS Server of a given workspace?
TLDR: Need admin rights to use $System.discover_object_memory_usage
